# Knockout JS Cannot bind to an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to bind array to a table, so it shows all my array contents.

I tried first example, which works (purely in HTML):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Model() {
        this.people = [
            { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington' },
            { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth' },
            { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Dentiste' }
        ];
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new Model());
</script>
```

Then I got to the next level, and tried bigger example, which always shows error

> Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return interests }"
>   Message: Anonymous template defined, but no template content was provided

Below is faulty code:

```js
// Activates knockout.js when document is loaded.
window.onload = (event) => {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
}

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

  this.fullName = ko.computed(() => this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(), this);

    this.interests = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "sport" },
        { name: "games" },
        { name: "books" },
        { name: "movies" }
    ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Interest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: interests"></tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tired already with regular array, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `<tbody>` before the inner template:

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
</tr>
```

So, the `tr` is now not in the context of the `foreach` binding.

Move the `</tbody>` to after the `</tr>` and before the `</table>` tags:

```js
// Activates knockout.js when document is loaded.
window.onload = (event) => {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
}

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

  this.fullName = ko.computed(() => this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(), this);

    this.interests = ko.observableArray([
        { name: "sport" },
        { name: "games" },
        { name: "books" },
        { name: "movies" }
    ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Interest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: interests">
      <tr>
          <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody> <!-- close here -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Interest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: interests">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
```